# Check if Firestore query is empty

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm running a query to check on a boolean (isLocked), to know if one or more of the documents are locked:

```
final CollectionReference ref = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection( "folders" ).document( user.getUid() ).collection( folder );

Query query = ref.whereEqualTo( "isLocked", true );
query.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
        boolean b = task.getResult().isEmpty();
        ToastEX.showShort( MainActivity.this, b ? "isLocked=1" : "isLocked=0");
    }
});
```

This always return *isLocked=1*, regardless of what's on the database.

How do I get this to work? Thanks a lot.

EDIT: Adding screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Since we can't see what's in your database, or see the values of your variables, it's hard to say if the query is actually doing what you think it's doing.  I find it hard to believe that the query is just plain wrong.  Try checking the contents of all the variables here, or hard code their values, in order to be absolutely certain you a querying what you really want.

Comment: I prefer `addOnCompleteListener` and check `task.getResult.isEmpty()` on a if statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you override the `onComplete()` method, always make sure to check if the task is successful like in the following lines of code:

```
if (task.isSuccessful()) {
    boolean b = task.getResult().isEmpty();
    ToastEX.showShort( MainActivity.this, b ? "isLocked=1" : "isLocked=0");
}  else {
    Log.d(TAG, "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
}
```

Try aslo not to forget to implement the `else` part to see if you have an error message.

Comment: getResult() will throw an unchecked exception if the task wasn't successfully completed, so this doesn't really address the issue.

Comment: Please add your database structure as a screenshot and please also show us the values of your `user.getUid()` and `folder` used in your reference.

Comment: Screenshot added. 'ggg' is folder. See document structure.

Comment: Have you tried to use hardocre values as also Doug Stevenson suggested? What's the result?

Comment: b = true when no document is locked and vice versa so I'm good now. Thanks Alex !